# Saving checked items from a listview to a file

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I cannot find a single article anywhere that explains how to actually persist the results of checkboxes within a ListView. Plenty show how to display but they all leave out how to save.

When I click 'Set Favourites' from a Menu item, I want to load a list of names and display a checkbox with each. I want to be able to make multiple 'checks' and then I want to be able to save the list in some form, with its checked settings, to some persistent storage, preferably on the SD card. The list just needs to contain a value for "name" and a value for "isChecked"

I'll just show the structure below, rather than all the code, as I think my problem is one of structure and scope, rather than syntax

In the main menu activity, I pass a list (checkedlist) into a custom adapter

```
public class SetFavourites extends ListActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    FavouritesAdapter adapter = new FavouritesAdapter(this, checkedList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The adapter has an onCheckedChangeListener, so whenever a checkbox is changed, at the point where I have written //Here's where I'm stuck, I will have the name and checked value for that row

```
public class FavouritesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> implements    OnCheckedChangeListener {

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

}

@Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {

    JSONObject checked = getItem(posSelected);

    // Here's where I'm stuck
}


}
```

So my question is how can I persist the data if there are multiple check events?

If I create a model to hold the row names and their checked status, then where do I instantiate that model - from the Activity, or from within the Adapter?

If within the Adapter, it has no event that tells when 'checking' is complete, so while it could add to a model, it can't do a save.

If the Adapter instantiates the model, how can the main activity save it? What event can I use to complete the data save? The back button method (which is defined within the main activity and therefore cannot act within the Adapter), or the Activity onStop() method, similarly.

If I instantiate the data model in the Activity and pass it in, how does it get passed out again to be saved?

As you can see, I'm totally confused with how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: If that is all you are wanting to save SharedPreferences seems like a better option to persist it. It will be simpler to implement also. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I would save state in an array list of whatever data type makes sense, then just transform that to a json array and serialize the json string to preferences assuming it's not some huge list, I use GSON to make this a lot easier.  I would just add a method to your adapter to do this.  Typically where you would persist data is in onPause of the activity. so adapter.saveState() or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used JSON but I've got a similar situation using a SQLite database.

So maybe I can give you the rough layout showing how I dealt with it and you can fill in the JSON bits and make it fit your needs.

In the custom adapter set an array:

```
public static int[] checked;
```

Have a constructor:

```
public FavouritesAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    initializeChecked();
}

public static void initializeChecked() {
    checked = new int[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < c.getCount()) {
        checked[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Then in your onCheckedChanged:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked == true){
        checked[posSelected] = 1;
    } else {
        checked[posSelected] = 0;
    }
}
```

Then the onClick for the button outside of the list to commit your changes:

```
commit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = 0;
        itemCursor.moveToFirst();  // existing cursor backing the list
        while (itemCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {  // iterate through cursor and match checked with rows
            if (FavouritesAdapter.checked[i] == 1) {
                // do your save to db/file/whatever here
        }
        i++;
        itemCursor.moveToNext();
    }
};
```

Not specific to your case, but hopefully you'll find it helpful.

Comment: This answer was close enough to allow me to overcome my 'log jam', which was a combination of not fully understanding 'static' class variables and constructors - so thanks for that! I'll post my own code in due course when I get it tidied up

Comment: Glad I could help... I wasn't sure how it would exactly relate to doing it with JSON, but it seems the basics should be somewhat the same.  I look forward to seeing your code, it oughta teach me something new.